# Show that sum $1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Question: Let $z=\cos(2\pi /n)+i\sin(2\pi /n)$ for an integer $n\geq2$. Show that $1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}=0$.

Work thus far: My initial idea is was to use euler's formula, but this leads to a sum of exponentials that can't be simplified easily. If I can separate the sum into two sums (one real, one imaginary) which both add to zero then I can show that the equality holds. Using DeMoivre's formula $z^a=\cos(a2\pi /n)+i\sin(a2\pi /n)$. So we get $$1+\cos(2\pi /n)+\cos(4\pi /n)+...+\cos(2n\pi/n)$$ $$i\sin(2\pi /n)+i\sin(4\pi /n)+...+i\sin(2n\pi/n)$$
From there however I do not know how to find the sum of both series.

Comment: I would draw the numbers up in the plane, and argue by symmetry.

Comment: Use the fact that your sum is a geometric series to simplify the sum.

Comment: Recall that $1+z +\cdots + z^{n-1} = \frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$.

Comment: Find a monic polynomial that has exactly those roots, and study the coefficient of the term with degree one less than that of your polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z = e^{2\pi i/n}$.  Now, note that:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} z^i = \frac{z^{n}-1}{z-1}$$
(by the finite geometric sum formula).  Putting in $e^{2\pi i/n}$, we get that:
$$\frac{e^{2\pi i/n\times n}-1}{e^{2\pi i/n}-1} = \frac{0}{e^{2\pi i/n}-1}$$
So, we have that the sum is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\{1,z,z^2,...,z^{n-1}\}$ are all of the $n$-th roots of unity. Using this fact, the multiplication with $z$ is a bijection on $\{1,z,z^2,...,z^{n-1}\}$, thus $$1+z+...+z^{n-1} = z+z^2+...+z^n = z(1+...+z^{n-1}).$$ Since $z\neq 1$, we can conclude that $1+...+z^{n-1} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is a finite geometric series and hence is equal to
$$
\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}
$$
Substitute $z=e^{2\pi i/n}$.